# Mysql subquery select all id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, inner-join

So, i need help doing a select inside a subquery, i know this is kinda basics but i can't manage to do it by myself yet.

(Reparacao=repairs and lojas=stores, from portuguese to english)

I want to get the number of repairs that each store has. However i can only do one store at a time, but i want a query that selects all the stores.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao ) , lojas.nome
FROM reparacoes
INNER JOIN lojas ON lojas.id = 1
WHERE id_loja = lojas.id
```

and i want something like:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao ) , lojas.nome
FROM reparacoes
INNER JOIN lojas ON lojas.id = (Select id from lojas)    //i want the id of every store
WHERE id_loja = lojas.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

There is no need to use sub query to fetch all repairs count by stores. 
You can easily get the result using **JOIN** and **GROUP BY**.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_reparacao) repairCnt, lojas.nome
FROM reparacoes
INNER JOIN lojas ON lojas.id = id_loja 
GROUP BY lojas.id
```

Comment: @Strawberry nice portuguese there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to join `ON` ids:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT r.id_reparacao ) , lojas.nome
FROM reparacoes r
INNER JOIN lojas l ON l.id = r.id_loja;
```